# Override equals method gives an error

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I'm a computer engineering student and I've started `Java` one week ago. I've been studying these days generic types and I wanted to mix it with equals and Overriding, so I wrote a program that creates an object called "Punto" with two attributes (pointX, pointY) so it simulates coordinates. I wrote a static method outside the main class that uses two "Puntos" as parameters and equals them. Here's the code of that method:

```
public static boolean iguales(PuntoImpl<Double> p1, PuntoImpl<Double> p2){
    return p1.equals(p2);
}
```

And here's my try of overriding equals:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof PuntoImpl)) 
        return false;

    PuntoImpl<T> other = (PuntoImpl<T>) obj;

    if (other.puntoX != this.puntoX)     return false;
    if (other.puntoY != this.puntoY)     return false;

    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to equals two points with same parameters in coordinate X and coordinate Y, but it returns me false. Can you help me to find the error?

Comment: what are the types of putoX and putoY ?

Comment: instanceof already does a null-check, you can leave the nullcheck if you do it like this, but I would recommend replacing the instanceof check by a check on equality of the actual classes.

Comment: They are T types (generic), but I'm using them as Double

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're comparing `Double` references. I suspect you want `if (!other.puntoX.equals(this.puntoX))`.

Comment: Please provide a runable example

Comment: also: Java and JavaScript are not (nearly) the same, just so you know.

Comment: @Stultuske thank you a lot, I didn't know that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing `Double` values by reference equality. I suspect you want `if (!other.puntoX.equals(this.puntoX))` etc. I'd actually write this code as:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    PuntoImpl<T> other = (PuntoImpl<T>) obj;

    return other.puntoX.equals(this.puntoX) &&
           other.puntoY.equals(this.puntoY);
}
```

Don't forget to override `hashCode` as well.

Also note that comparing floating point values for exact equality can often give unexpected results. Instead of overriding `equals`, you may want to provide a way of finding the distance between points, so you can compare them with a certain tolerance.

Comment: Shouldn't if (obj == this) return true?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Sorry, yes - C&P fail.

Comment: @JonSkeet now it's finally working! Thank you a lot for your answer, it was really easy to understand :)